# How to upgrade mongodb from 2.0 to 2.2 in mac osx

Tags: macos, mongodb, upgrade

There are no instructions that I can find on the mongodb website on how to install 2.2 when you already have 2.0 using brew.  I can see versions using "brew versions mongodb" but when I try to install one it says "mongodb does not have a version "2.2.0-x86_64" in the Cellar."

The versions command shows:

```
new-host-4:~ scott$ brew versions mongodb
2.2.0-x86_64 git checkout 34fb67d /usr/local/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
2.0.7-x86_64 git checkout 6434ebb /usr/local/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
2.0.6-x86_64 git checkout 2553479 /usr/local/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
...
```

I know it's only a few lines of magic but I don't know the proper incantation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All I had to do was the following...

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade mongodb
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also added
   brew switch mongodb 2.2.0-x86_64

I was doing
    brew install mongodb 2.2.0-x86_64
    Error: No available formula for 2.2.0-x86_64 

Didn't know to leave off the version number

Comment: +1 - elegant and simple than some other posts which suggested copying db files over.